# Commutative Property under Matrix multiplication

Tags: matrices, group-theory

I am asked to show that the set of matrices
$$G=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1&a&b\\0&1&c\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}:a,b,c\in\mathbb Q\right\}$$
form an abelian group wrt matrix multiplication. (Assume that matrix multiplication is associative).

I know that for $G$ to form an abelian group under matrix multiplication,

1. Matrix multiplication in $G$ should be associative.
2. Existence of identity element in matrix multiplication.
3. Existence of inverse element in matrix multiplication.
4. Matrix multiplication in $G$ should be commutative.

For $1$, it is already given that matrix multiplication is associative.

For $2$, I have found the identity element $a = b = c = 0$.

For $3$, I have similarly found the inverse element.

But for $4$, I am unable to prove that $AB = BA$ for all $A,B\in G$ containing terms a1,b1,c1,a2,b2,c2 since a1c2 is not equal to a2c1.

How do show that $G$ is an abelian group under matrix multiplication? Please help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: For part 1. one should note that the operation is "closed", i.e., the matrix product of two upper-unitriangular matrices is again upper-unitriangular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't prove commutativity because it's false. Let
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}\qquad B=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&1\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$
Then
$$AB=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\0&1&1\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}\ne\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0\\0&1&1\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}=BA$$
$G$ is still a group under matrix multiplication, but not an *abelian* group.

Comment: Okay, Thanks! The question is also asking about center of G. I think the center of G is {0, 1, a,b,c}, Is it correct?

Comment: sir your answer is very helpful to me and I upvoted it. But unfortunately I'm having less than 15 reputation for that. Please say if I'm right or wrong regarding the center of G sir.

Comment: sir how do I accept it? Please tell the steps

Comment: Thank You so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The question must have meant to say *non*-Abelian. Incidentally, this is called the [Heisenberg group](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group).

Comment: Here it is the Heisenberg group over $\Bbb Q$. The coefficients can be an arbitrary commutative ring with identity (see the link).