# Center of a Group matrix

Tags: group-theory

Consider the set of matrices G = {[1, a, b; 0, 1, c; 0, 0, 1] : a, b, c belong to Q (set of rational numbers)}
Given that matrix multiplication is associative, find the center of G.

Since we know that the center of a group, Z(G) = {a belong to G: ax=xa for all x belong to G}
Hence Z(G) = {0, 1, a, b, c} for all a, b, c belong to Q

Is it correct?

Comment: It's wrong: the elements of $G$ are matrices, so $Z(G)$ should consist of matrices.

Comment: @Berci Sir can I say Z(G) is equal to G with the condition that a=c ?

Comment: If you want to make it easier for people to read your question, and therefore to have a larger pool of potential answerers, please typeset your question using [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). You can even do [matrices](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/5023#5023).

Comment: @Tanay Yes, that's much better.

Comment: This is the *Heisenberg group*, which you know from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3632745/commutative-property-under-matrix-multiplication). It's center is generated by the matrix with $b=1$ and $a=c=0$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde that only generates the matrices with integer entries.

Comment: Ah, yes, I forgot that we have $\Bbb Q$ here. But no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Just multiply two such generic matrices:
$$\pmatrix{1&a&b\\&1&c\\&&1}\cdot \pmatrix{1&x&y\\&1&z\\&&1}\ =\ \pmatrix{1& x+a& y+az+b\\&1&z+c\\&&1}$$
If we exchange the variables $a,b,c$ with $x,y,z$, hence the order of the two matrices, we arrive to
$$\pmatrix{1& a+x& b+xc+y\\&1&c+z\\&&1}\,. $$

> So, they commute iff $az=xc$, and for fixed $a,b,c$, this happens for all $x,y,z$ only if $a=c=0$.